# SAP Logic apps create creditor with input parameter

Tags: azure-logic-apps, sap-erp, bapi

I try to create a creditor in SAP with logic apps using SAP BAPI.
I have a connection from Azure logic app to sap with the local Datagateway. But does I need also an RFC Connection in SAP and where I should register the Program-ID from my RFC Connection from SAP.
[image: RFC Connection1]
[image: RFC Connection2]

First I tried to read existing creditors. This step give me an OK message but I don't see the results in my logic app.
[image: Step - Send message to SAP]

Then the more important step for me to create a creditor with the needed input parameters like Name and company code.
But this step I get an error in logic apps designer.
[image: Step - Call method in SAP1]
[image: Step - Call method in SAP2]

I'm completely new in this and I want to know which parameter or Business Object I should use and what is the syntax to do what I want.

I hope some experts can help me because we need that next week.

Thanks in advance.
Greetings Franco

Comment: Please post the full messages as they are currently truncated in the screenshots.

Comment: also, it is better to put messages in text, than in screenshot. It makes them more readable, copyable and makes your post less cluttered